# SwiftUI: Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift5

I wrote an extension for SwiftUI Font which introduces a couple of custom fonts.

```swift
extension Font {
    static let solDisplay: Font = .custom("Gilroy", size: 36)
    static let solHeadline: Font = .custom("Gilroy", size: 24)
}
```

Now for some reason there is the following error appears during the build process: `Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'heavy'`.
Interestingly this error was found by someone else while doing a Pull Request - I did not notice any of these errors locally, but it appears to happen to only some. Currently 2 out of 4 people in our team have the errors where the other ones don't.

```swift
struct AssetsDemoPage: View {
    let fonts: [(String, Font)] = [
        ("Display - Heavy", .solDisplay.weight(.heavy)),   // Error Happening here
        ("Display - Light", .solDisplay),                  // No error here!
        ("Headline - Heavy", .solHeadline.weight(.heavy)), // Error Happening here
        ("Headline - Light", .solHeadline),                // No error here!
    ]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Section(header: Text("Fonts")) {
                    ForEach(fonts, id: \.0) { name, font in
                        Text(name)
                            .font(font)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Assets"), displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the people not experiencing the errors using Xcode 12.5 and the people who *are* using 12.4?

Comment: Working in 12.5 for me. Regardless of it it helps, why not switch to `KeyValuePairs<String, Font>` or [`OrderedDictionary`](https://github.com/apple/swift-collections/blob/main/Documentation/OrderedDictionary.md)?

Comment: I solved it by importing UIKit

Comment: @pkc456 How would importing UIKIt help as importing SwiftUI already includes UIKit?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As @jnpdx is referring to with the Xcode versions, the Swift version may not be the same. In Swift 5.4, [SE-0287](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0287-implicit-member-chains.md) was implemented.

This proposal allowed for implicit member chains. You can read more on the proposal linked, but this sums it up pretty well:

> This proposal suggests the expansion of implicit member syntax to more complex expressions than just a single static member or function. Specifically, implicit member syntax would be allowed to cover chains of member references.

Code such as `Color.red.opacity(0.5)` can now be simplified to `.red.opacity(0.5)`, similar to in your example.

Xcode 12.5 is required to use Swift 5.4, so let the team know to upgrade.